# (builtins.TypeError) SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, try-catch

I Tried many ways of inserting date in my SQLAlchemy object. But gives error.

My route file:

```
app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    reply = {}
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        password_hash = generate_password_hash(data['password'])
        datelist = data['birthdate'].split('-')
        bdate = datetime.date(int(datelist[0]), int(datelist[1]), int(datelist[2]))
        new_user = Entities.User(id = uuid.uuid4(), username = data['username'], fullname = data['fullname'], email = data['email'], password_hash = password_hash, birthdate = bdate)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        reply['status'] = "OK"
        reply['message'] = ""
    except Exception as e:
        reply['status'] = "FAIL"
        reply['message'] = str(e)
    return jsonify(reply)
```

My User Class of SQLAlchemy:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25), index=True, unique=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(25), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    imagelink = db.Column(db.String(300), default = "some.url.unspecified.com")
    bio = db.Column(db.String(700), default = "No Bio Added")
    datejoined = db.Column(db.Date, default = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    birthdate = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

My Query's JSON Body:
I am firing this to localhost. `http://127.0.0.1:5001/signup`

```
{
    "username":"amandesai01",
    "fullname":"Aman Desai",
    "password":"xyz123",
    "email":"amandesai01@gmail.com",
    "birthdate":"2000-10-14"
}
```

Response I am getting:

```
{
  "message": "(builtins.TypeError) SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input.\n[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id, username, fullname, email, password_hash, imagelink, bio, datejoined, birthdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: [{'password_hash': 'pbkdf2:sha256:150000$CPZYKMPJ$b4e0f3a01e17e533a92cd21709b1e4f496f068bd19c8b31fa2723cbbf1ea6beb', 'id': UUID('0e8f6414-27af-4ca9-8e72-a0f4974a0b0d'), 'fullname': 'Aman Desai', 'birthdate': datetime.date(2000, 10, 14), 'email': 'amandesai01@gmail.com', 'username': 'amandesai01'}]]",
  "status": "FAIL"
}
```

Comment: I can't understand, exactly which date object they need. I tried datetime.date but didn't work :(

Comment: `datejoined = db.Column(db.Date, default = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))` has an interesting default.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the problem. Try this

1. First you need to import `datetime` class.

```
from datetime import datetime, date
```

2. Now apply this change to your `"birthdate"` column.

```
{
    "username":"amandesai01",
    "fullname":"Aman Desai",
    "password":"xyz123",
    "email":"amandesai01@gmail.com",
    "birthdate": datetime.date(2000-10-14)
}
```

3. To get current date(today date) use this command

```
datejoined = db.Column(db.Date, default = date.today())
```

Comment: Unless the application is restarted every day, `default = datetime.date.today()` is a bad choice for a default. The default should be the `date.today` function itself. From looking at the question and the response it's obvious that they're already converting the birthdate before passing it as a value, and the issue is likely with the string-default of `datejoined`. `datetime.date(2000-10-14)` is valid Python, but raises an exception, because passing 1 integer argument `1976` is not the way to call `date()`.

Comment: When I was editing my answer I have done few mistakes. I have edited it

Comment: @Kalana you haven't addressed the problem raised by Ilja.

Answer (score 0):

Your could fetch the date from the data as a string then convert as like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = data['birthdate']

bdate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Check [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-string-to-datetime-strptime#converting-a-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-datetime-strptime) for more